# Bind 9 problems

Tags: dns

Can anyone evaluate my bind zone files and tell me where I'm going wrong? This is my first time writing zone files, so something is probably wrong. I'm using Bind9. After I write these zone files, I do nslookup for this domain

> nslookup admitonetwowire1.com localhost

and get

> Can't find admitonetwowire1.com: No answer

. Here are the zone files:

**db.admitonetwowire1.com**

```
;
; BIND data file for admitonetwowire1.com
;
$TTL 1d
@     IN    SOA   localhost. mmpresti.admitonetwowire1.com. (
                                         2
                                        604800
                                         86400
                                         2419200
                                         604800)

@     IN     NS    localhost.

localhost IN A     127.0.0.1
mmpresti IN    A     192.168.0.2
server   IN    A     192.168.0.2

@     IN     MX    5 server.admitonetwowire1.com.
```

**db.2.0.168.192**

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA localhost. mmpresti.admitonetwowire1.com. (
2
604800
86400
2419200
604800 )

@ IN A  192.168.0.2
@ IN NS localhost.
@ IN PTR server.admitonetwowire1.com.
@ IN PTR mmpresti.admitonetwowire1.com.
```

**named.conf.local**

```
zone "admitonetwowire1.com" {
    type master; 
    file "/etc/bind/db.admitonetwowire1.com"; 
};  

zone "2.0.168.192" { 
    type master; 
    file "/etc/bind/db.2.0.168.192"; 
};
```

I've run a syntax check on all of this, so that's not the problem, it's somewhere in my content. Some help would be appreciated, thanks.

revised db.2.0.168.192

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA admitonetwowire1.com root.admitonetwowire1.com (
2
604800
86400
2419200
604800 )

@ IN PTR  192.168.0.2
@ IN PTR admitonetwowire1.com.
@ IN NS admitonetwowire1.com.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add admitonetwowire1.com in SOA in the place of localhost , then give it A record , and NS record and also in the reverse zone .

Comment: Everything is going fine so far in the forward zone, however, in the reverse zone, when I try to add an A record for admitonetwowire1.com like so: @ IN A admitonetwowire1.com  , I get an error that says "bad quad" on that line. It doesn't have a trailing dot, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: there should be dot at the end of com.

Comment: it's giving me the same error whether the dot is there or no.

Comment: delete local host

Comment: here's what the revised file looks like:

Comment: up above in the original post.

Comment: changed it to PTR record, and it loaded

Comment: pftttt i didn't notice that you are in reverse zone :)

Comment: ch-ching! and the nslookup is now bringing up my zone! Thanks, nux.

Comment: welcome dear dont forget to mark it as answer  , good to hear that it works